# Is there a way to detect the subnet from an IP address?

Tags: python, network-programming

I am working on a script to quickly configure IPKVMs for a corporate network and the KVMs require both an IP and subnet to be set. The is script currently set up for my small group and can either pull an available IP from our /23 subnet or can use a manually assigned on.

However, now that I'm developing this for a wider userbase, I need to account for the various subnet configurations throughout the corporate network. **So my question would be, is there a way for me to detect the subnet configuration from an IP address provided by the user?** That way if the script is fed an IP of 10.10.10.1, it could detect the subnet configuration and append the appropriate subnet within the KVM configuration.

I'm targeting this to be for an audience that may not have a lot of network knowledge or know the specifics of how theirs is set up. So I'm hoping to take some of the guesswork out of it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Networking is not actually a programming topic, but no,  in addition to the IP you need an information about the size of the subnet.

Comment: If a user can provide the IP address, then the user can provide the network mask. If you do a bitwise `AND` on the address and mask, the result is the network address. See [this two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) for how to do that.